# Why does the Inbuild property "SheetNames" is not woking?

Tags: angular, typescript, xlsx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B9Jg.png)**Error: src/app/Components/upload-file/upload-file.component.ts:22:33 - error TS2339: Property 'SheetNames' does not exist on type 'number'.

22       var sheetNames = workBook.SheetNames;
~~~~~~~~~~**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the minus '-' you have in front of `XLSX.read(...)`.

The `+` or `-` operator infront of a value will effectively convert it to a number.